# Export only top level data while exporting xamDataGrid bound to hierarchical data source

Tags: export, export-to-excel, hierarchical-data, xamdatagrid

I'm using XamDataGrid in WPF Application. XamDataGrid is bound to hierarchical data source. I'm using ExportAsync() method to export data for xamDataGrid. It is exporting parent and child level but I need to export only parent/top level data. How to export only top level data while exporting xamDataGrid?'

```
XamDataGrid xamDataGrid = xamGridExporter.AssociatedObject;
    if (xamDataGrid.Records.Count > 0)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel2007|*.xlsx|Excel97To2003|*.xls|Excel97To2003Template|*.xlt", DefaultExt = "xls" };
        DataPresenterExcelExporter exporter = xamGridExporter.ExporterResource;
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog().Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            WorkbookFormat format = SetWorkBookFormat(Path.GetExtension(saveFileDialog.FileName));
            ExportOptions exportOptions = new ExportOptions();
            exporter.ExportAsync(xamDataGrid, saveFileDialog.FileName, format, exportOptions);
        }
    }
```

I'm using above code to export data.

Thanks,
Disha

Answer (score 0):

I am able to skip child records while exporting using InitializeRecord event of the DataPresenterExcelExporter being used for the export.
I this event check if record is data record and it has children, then set e.SkipDescendants to true.

```
static void exporter_InitializeRecord(object sender, InitializeRecordEventArgs e)
    {
            DataRecord record = e.Record as DataRecord;
            if (record != null && record.ParentRecord == null && record.HasChildren)
                e.SkipDescendants = true;
    }
```

Thanks,
Disha